# efficiently check whether remote tracking branch changed (git or gitlab)

Tags: linux, performance, git, cron, gitlab

I'm looking for the fastest way of finding out, whether a remote tracking branch is different from a current branch.

Context:
Id' like to run a cron job, that shall find out, whether the current HEAD of the local branch is identical to its remote tracking branch. There might be hundreds of hosts running this cron job(each might be on a different branch / HEAD). So I'd like to implement this as fast and efficient as possible. (least possible network load and CPU load on git server)

At the moment I perform a `git fetch` and then `git status`.
However even if other branches changed on the remote host `git fetch` will be busy for some time and `git status` is also not that efficient.

The repository is hosted on a gitlab server (https access only, repositories require authentification)

So a pure git solution is as appreciated as a gitlab solution.

I'd like to implement the solution as a `bash` script or as a `python` script. `pip install` of any helpful dependency is not an issue.

In fact I'd like to perform this check for a couple of repositories on a host  (all accessible with the same credentials).
I guess, that if I can optimize one check, then I'll be as good as possible, and I'll perform this check for each repository.

However if there is a trick to improve performance by querying for multiple repositories with one script, then this is also an option. (e.g. authenticate only once, query multiple repositories)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `git ls-remote` to list all remote refs and their object IDs.

```
git ls-remote origin
git ls-remote origin refs/heads/master
```

The same command works against local repositories, but `git rev-parse` will be more efficient there.

```
git ls-remote .
git rev-parse refs/heads/master
git rev-parse master
```

The current branch is set by having HEAD be a "symbolic" ref to another ref:

```
branch=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD)
```

However, if you're going to fetch the updates *anyway*, then might as well go straight to `git fetch` with the specific branch ref.

```
git fetch origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
git fetch origin master:origin/master
```

The fetched branch always becomes a ref which you can compare in the same way:

```
git rev-parse refs/heads/master
git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master
```

(The full ref names can almost always be shortened to just `master:origin/master` but I wouldn't put that in a script.)

Comment: Thanks a lot.

`git rev-parse HEAD` doesn't seem to indicate me on which branch I am.
So I had to use  `branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)` to get the branch, then `mycommit=$(git rev-parse HEAD)` to get my branch and then something like `rmt_commit=$(git ls-remote | grep "heads/$branch$" | awk '{ print $1}')`, right?

Will check the performance. But it's almost definitely more performant than what I do at the moment. Will still wait for other answers / suggestions.

Comment: no exactly In some cases (for some repositories I'd like to fetch the changes to the current branch immediately) for some others I'd just like to know, that I could perform a pull / fetch.

Comment: Saw that you updated your answer:
So this is what you propose?
`branch=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD)` then `mycommit=$(git rev-parse refs/heads/master)` then `rmt_commit=$(git ls-remote origin $branch | awk '{print $1}')`

Comment: That'll work, assuming that the local branch will be named exactly the same as its remote upstream.

Comment: yep that (the naming style of local / rmt branches) is the case in our setup. Thanks.
I guess it will be tough to be more efficient. Will still wait a little for other potential answers though.

Comment: Any idea of how to get the tracking branch for `$branch` (so how to get `refs/remotes/origin/master` if all what I have is `refs/heads/master` ?

Comment: Thanks. my code is much faster than before now

Comment: I don't know of a command to map ref names (however the mapping itself is stored as a "refspec" in the `remote.origin.fetch` config parameter). In general you could probably safely assume that `refs/heads/$branch` will be fetched as `refs/remotes/$remote/$branch`.

Comment: (Note that in my 1st `git fetch` example the mapping is just bypassed -- you can fetch to any name you prefer, e.g. `git fetch origin refs/heads/master:refs/tmp/fetched`. You can even omit the :destination part and it'll default to FETCH_HEAD.)